# Why is Iridatsu Yuuta's ghost the way that it is?

Tags: punchline

Iridatsu Yuuta spends most of the series as a ghost. The ghost is shaped just like Yuuta, but with ghostly lower body-ish.

But later we learn that

> Yuuta's body is not his own. Yuuta's is actually Pine from the lab children flashback, has white-ish hair. The body he is inhabiting actually belongs to Narugino/Chiyoko.

What is the in-universe reason that Yuuta's ghost is shaped like that, given the information above?

I can guess at the out-of-universe explanation, it is pretty obvious that

> Were his ghost to be diffferent from the body, it would spoil the disclosure of the body switch plot.

Comment: It's been ten-ish years since the body swap, right? I figure that by this point, Yuuta identifies with his new body more than with his old one, so his ghost also shows up that way. (Pure speculation, though; I don't know if there is textual support for this explanation.)

Comment: @senshin i don't know either, but where else is better to dig something if there is?